# Set ESRI JavaScript Api's starting point on page load

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have the following block of code in my .js file:

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView) {
  var map = new Map({
      center: [-46.807, 32.553],
      basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",  // Reference to the DOM node that will contain the view
    map: map               // References the map object created in step 3
  });
});
```

The results is, as expected, a map of the whole world. How can I set the starting extent of the map to be my city, so clients will know my company's location. I've tried using the `extent` option, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a good explanation on ESRI's website:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_currentextent.html